# Cron job could not open input file

Tags: php, cron

I have a `cron job` on my hosting server that is supposed to execute a `php`script every 30 minutes. This `php` script is used to scrap a `csv` file and uptate that data into a database (i'm using MySQL for that). When executed manually that script works - it takes it about `45 seconds` to finish the process.

Now when that `cron job` runs i'm getting this message:

```
Could not open input file.
```

At first i thought that this might be because it takes over 30 seconds to execute that script so i decided to set the max execution time at the begging of the php script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

But again the same message came up.
This is my `cron job`:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/emmaein/domain.com/folder/script.php?token=d8cn3j
```

P.S: that `token` get variable is sort of a password so it can't be executed by everybody so basically my `php` script looks like this:

```
if($_GET['token'] === 'd8cn3j'){
    //open csv
    //get data
    //update db
} else{
    exit('I see you >:)');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When PHP is not running inside a web server, you can't access `$_GET` variables (there's no such thing). Instead you should use command line arguments:

```php
<?php
if ($argc > 1 && $argv[1] === 'd8cn3j') {
    // Do stuff
}
```

And then your crontab becomes:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/emmaein/domain.com/folder/script.php d8cn3j
```

The concept of `$argc` (the number of arguments) and `$argv` (an array of the arguments) is fairly standard among CLI programs, and [is documented on PHP's website](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

Comment: hey @SeanBright, can you please tell me how is that `$argv` array obtained/formed? :s

Comment: hey @SeanBright, now i understand annnd it works! Thank you so much for your help! :D